# How to delete all the characters until the n'th occurence of character X from a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am kinda new to python. I'm reading lines from a text file and store them in a string variable. Each line is in the following format:

```
text:text"text":"text":"extract":"text."text:"....
```

I want to delete all the characters from the string until the n'th ocurrence of the character " and save the word extract. 
Could someone help me on how to do this ? I'm using python3

Example:

```
str=text:text"text":"text":"extract":"text."text:"
someoperation(str)
print(str) #should return extract
```

str arrays have different numbers of characters.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Comment: Just as a side note, the link talks about arrays, but python strings are essentially immutable arrays. This means you can't change characters in place like this. `my_str = 'some value'`  `my_str[2] = 'a'`. You can however get around it by just reassigning it to the same variable like so.  `my_str = 'some value'`  `my_str = my_str[:2] + 'a' + my_str[3:]`.

Comment: Hello, your answer is usefull when you have the same amount of characters in the array, but my arrays have variable length, but have a fixed number of " characters so I need to extract the names from them:

Comment: If strings work like arrays, I think I know how to deal with this problem, with a function that searches for the character " in the string array and returns the position of it and then I just slice a number of times trough the string array.

Comment: strings have a useful method for that. `.find()` For example, `'test"test'.find('"')` will return `4`, the position of the `"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `str.replace` which accepts the number of occurrences to replace.

```py
In [1]: s = "1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9"

In [2]: s.replace("-", "", 3)
Out[2]: '1234-5-6-7-8-9'
```

note that the replace function doesn't change the value of s, but return a new string that can be assigned to a variable. strings are immutable in python as mentioned in the comment to your post.

Comment: thanks, I want to delete all the characters not only the " , but this can be implemented using find and replace. :)

Comment: You might want to have a look at `re.subn` which will let you replace a match of a regex with a given string